# FMX - Adding LineBreak to LocalNotification

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, uilocalnotification

Embarcadero has a [good article](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_Notifications) explaining how to use Local Notifications on `Android`.

However, when I add `sLineBreak` to the `AlertBody` of my `LocalNotification`, it doesn't add any line breaks at all.

```
 // Set the alert message
 LocalNotification.AlertBody := g_name + ' sent:' + sLineBreak + last_notification_event;
```

How can I add a `LineBreak` for a `LocalNotification` on `Firemonkey`?

Comment: try #13#10 instead of sLineBreak

Comment: I did try `#13#10` but just like led zeppellin it all remains the same

Comment: @USKMobility: Nonsense. The entire purpose of the `sLineBreak` constant is to contain the proper line ending for the platform the code is compiled for; using a hard-coded Windows line break would simply be foolish.

Comment: AFAIK, Android notifications don't allow multiple paragraphs, and that would be the only purpose for adding a line break. I could be wrong, but I don't recall getting multiple-paragraph notifications.

Comment: @KenWhite , are you sure? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Comment: @tardoandre: No. If I had been sure, I wouldn't have said AFAIK, and I wouldn't have said *I could be wrong*. :-) I don't see any multi-paragraph notifications in the link you posted, either. I see multi-**line**, but that's simple word wrap that you don't need to add a line break to have; it happens automatically.

Comment: Well.. unfortunately it's not happening automatically :-(